# How do I get my ajax function to handle requests one by one?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, each

I have a bunch of twitch channels with their names as ID and want to ascribe the correct status to the channel and keep it at "offline" if I don't get a result. It all works fine, except which channel is getting which status is pretty much random, most of the time the last one is the only one that's affected. How do I get .ajax to simply do one request at a time? (I already tried putting async: false)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var names = [];
  var status = 'Offline';
  var iconColor = "#B00";

  $('.channel').each(function(index) {
    names.push($(this).attr('id'));
  });

  $(".channel").each(function(index) {
    iconColor = "#B00";
    $(this).html('<div class="iconStatus col-md-1"><i class="fa fa-television" aria-hidden="true"></i></div><a href="https://www.twitch.tv/' + names[index] + '"><div class="nameChannel col-md-3"></div></a><div class="status col-md-8">Offline</div>');
    $(this).children("a").children(".nameChannel").text(names[index]);
    $.ajax({
      url: 'https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/streams/' + names[index],
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      type: 'GET',
      async: false,
      jsonpCallback: 'JSON_CALLBACK',
      success: function(data) {
        if (data.stream !== null) {
          assignProps(names[index], data.stream.channel.status, '#0B0');
        }
      }
    });
  });
});

function assignProps(name, status, iconColor) {
  $('#' + name).children('.status').text(status);
  $('#' + name).children('.iconStatus').children('i').css('color', iconColor);
};
```

Comment: did you try to log the data object to make sure you are actually getting all the data back? what does it say?

Comment: yes, I am getting each object

Comment: but in random order

Comment: well, yes, the server is going to respond asynchronously so you should be getting a random order, that's how it should work

Answer (score 0):

I have removed async and jsonpCallback. The reason is, for async, requests will freeze browser for request time. jsonpCallback is maintained by jQuery, so there is no need to set it.

I moved `names` to global scope from onload handler, and added `nameIndex` to track for what name I will fetch stream data next.

Then, instead of calling ajax for each channel in the second `$(".channel").each(function(index)`, I made function `fetchStream` that will call it for next name for `names` based on `nameIndex` and it will then call itself on `complete` handler of last ajax request, it means it will call itself either on `error` or `success`. You may want to handle `error` yourself to decrement nameIndex and call `fetchStream` will make a request for the same index again, but be careful to not pitfall into infinite loop if error will occur every time.

```js
var names = [];
var nameIndex = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {
  var status = 'Offline';
  var iconColor = "#B00";

  $('.channel').each(function(index) {
    names.push($(this).attr('id'));
  });

  $(".channel").each(function(index) {
    iconColor = "#B00";
    $(this).html('<div class="iconStatus col-md-1"><i class="fa fa-television" aria-hidden="true"></i></div><a href="https://www.twitch.tv/' + names[index] + '"><div class="nameChannel col-md-3"></div></a><div class="status col-md-8">Offline</div>');
    $(this).children("a").children(".nameChannel").text(names[index]);
  });
  
  fetchStream();
});

function fetchStream(){
  if(nameIndex < names.length){
    var name = names[nameIndex];
    console.log('Fetching for ' + name);
    $.ajax({
      url: 'https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/streams/' + name,
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      type: 'GET',
      success: function(data) {
        if (data.stream !== null) {
          assignProps(name, data.stream.channel.status, '#0B0');
        }
      },
      complete: function(){
        fetchStream();
      }
    });
    
    nameIndex++;
  } else {
    console.log('Finished');
  }
}

function assignProps(name, status, iconColor) {
  $('#' + name).children('.status').text(status);
  $('#' + name).children('.iconStatus').children('i').css('color', iconColor);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="channel" id="lirik"></div>
<div class="channel" id="yuuhi"></div>
<div class="channel" id="esl_overwatch"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that was exactly what I needed